# MongoDB weird behavior needs explanation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So yesterday I started messing around with MongoDB in Node and when it comes to retrieving data I encountered a weird practice.
You retrieve data from a collection that is nested within a database by calling.

```
data = client.db([dbname]).collection([collectionname]).find([searchcriteria])
```

and this returns what seems to be an object at least in the eyes of typeof

the sample code then uses the following lines to log it to the console:

```
function iterate(x){ 
    console.log(x)
}
data.forEach(iterate)
```

The output is as expected in this case two objects with 2 pairs everything is fine so far.

I thought it is a bit unnecessary to have the iterate function so I changed that to just

```
console.log(data)
```

expecting the 2 objects in a array or nested in another object but what i get is this huge object with all kinds of different things in it **EXCEPT the two objects that we saw before**.

So now to my Question and what I need deeper explanation on:

why can i actually use `.forEach()` on this object I cannot recreate this on other objects.

and the second thing is why is `console.log(data)` giving me all this output that is hidden if I call it through `.forEach()`?

and is there any other way to quickly within one or 2 lines of code retrieve data from Mongo ?

this seems to be a very not useful way of doing things.
and how does this `.forEach()` thing on objects work I found a article here on stack however this was not very detailed and not very easy to understand.

Comment: forEach used for array object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` function returns a cursor - this is the huge object that you are seeing. Checkout documentation for more details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find

The reason why you can call `forEach` on the returned object (=cursor), is because it is one of its methods. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach

Overview of all cursor methods is here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/

To get the array of data that you are looking for you need to use the `toArray` method, like so:

```
const data = client.db([dbname]).collection([collectionname]).find([searchcriteria]).toArray()
```

Comment: Thanks You have been the most helpful guy on this community and you were nice while doing so! For the first time I've not been lynched for asking a well noob question i scrambled the docs of course but they are rather messy and i couldn't find that maybe i just overseen it. But thanks for helping not full time and newcomers.